# allowed values for actual_type_n and persisted_type_n in alf_node_properties table in Alfresco

Tags: alfresco

What are the allowed values for actual_type_n and persisted_type_n in alf_node_properties table in Alfresco.
Please provide any pointers on the mapping details.

Mapping details for actual_type_n and persisted_type_n in alf_node_properties table

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Why are you messing around with the low-level Alfresco databases? Why not just use the standard Alfresco APIs and let Alfresco store/retrieve everything?

Comment: @Gagravarr Just guessing, but one really good reason to access the db directly would be reporting/BI. Neither the public api, nor Alfresco Search Services are suitable for this use case and it would not be difficult to perform a basic reporting with such a mapping in the DB. Another approach (with Alfresco 7) would be to populate an external DB via Out of Processes API to fill the desired fact table(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values for actual_type_n and persisted_type_n are resovled and handled by the [NodeDAO](https://github.com/Alfresco/alfresco-community-repo/blob/master/repository/src/main/java/org/alfresco/repo/domain/node/NodeDAO.java) / [NodePropertyHelper](https://github.com/Alfresco/alfresco-community-repo/blob/master/repository/src/main/java/org/alfresco/repo/domain/node/NodePropertyHelper.java). The `persisted_type_n` column specifies the column containing the property value in the database and `actual_type_n` is the reference to the correspondig Java type.

Unfortunately the map to resolve these ids is implemented in Java Code only and therefore not available from inside the database. Maybe someone has already written a helper class to dump out that map to make db queries easier?